# Reference external file as a function

Tags: admin, admin-menu, callbacks

In my functions.php I have the following code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'jp_create_admin_pages' );

function jp_create_admin_pages()
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Members',
        'Members',
        'manage_options',
        'members',
        'admin-members.php');
}
```

In the same folder, I have another file called admin-members.php with the following code:

```
<span>Hello Admin World!</span>
```

However, I am getting a PHP error saying that this is an invalid callback (it works when I replace the 'admin-members.php' parameter with the name of a function in functions.php).

How can I reference an external file as a callback so that this will work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t. Create a function that loads that file:

```
function load_admin_page_file()
{
    require 'admin-members.php';
}
```

Then use that function name as callback argument.

In PHP 5.3 you can use a lambda:

```
add_menu_page(
    'Members',
    'Members',
    'manage_options',
    'members',
    function() { require 'admin-members.php'; }
);
```

Comment: Could you please wait until I finished my answer before posting? Thanks ;)

Comment: @kaiser Nope. I knew you would write a novel where a simple snippet can solve the problem. So I wrote that snippet.

Answer (score 2):

## Programming and machines

As machines are "stupid", they need to be programmed. And programming languages don't work like languages spoken by humans as programs/machines as they can't *interpret* what the human thinks. They need a clear and unique advice what and when to something we order them. If you for e.g. define the function `getBlock()` twice, the machine would `throw` and `Exception` to handle that failure and notify the human about *his* error. The machine will not even question if it should `return` you a building block or a solid square sided something. Therefore this isn't possible (in this case) and you have to stick to the rule that the program needs a clear advice that gives it some argument/parameter that is *within the boundaries* of what it expects.

## The needed argument within the boundaries

As the program told you, it needs a `callback`, which is either a `function` or a `method` of `array( 'ObjectName', 'methodName' )`. So you have to feed it with one or the other.

## A work around

As you can do nearly everything within a function or method, you can as well advice it to load your file. Depending on the way you load it, you can either just `require` or `include` that file or `redirect` to it:

```
function wpse98197_redirect_admin_page()
{
    # You can simply load them...
    # (Both are equal in what they do, but not in how they handle errors)
    // require_once 'admin-members.php';
    // include_once 'admin-members.php';

    # Or replace the current page with the desired file
    exit( wp_redirect( get_stylesheet_uri().'admin-members.php' ) );
}
```

Comment: Nice answer - one followup - is there such thing as lambda statements in PHP?  With C# if a method takes a function as a parameter (i.e. a delegate), you could do this: add_action('admin_menu', () => { require 'admin-members.php'; }.  (or something like that - I can't remember the syntax off of the top of my head).

Comment: @William There are [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) in PHP - php.net for the rescue. But I wouldn't recommend using them on hooks or filters. They are extremely hard to remove and impossible to debug. Aside from that, you have to notice the [difference between lambda functions and closures](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/17/on-php-5-3-lambda-functions-and-closures), where closures are not yet available with the default PHP version WP requires: 5.2.1.